# Asymptotic behavior of the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\rho \cosh(R)}\cosh(Rq)dR$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, descent

Which method can I use to study the asymptotic behavior as $\rho \to \infty$ of the integral for $q \geq 0$?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\rho \cosh(R)}\cosh(Rq)dR$$

I wish to study this behavior to understand more about modified Bessel functions and since I never studied in my life methods to study the behavior of functions, a detailed explanation on why the chosen method is the best to be applied will be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Method of Steepest Descent, see [here](http://www.ma.man.ac.uk/~gajjar/MATH44011/notes/44011_note4.pdf).

Comment: Even if I consider my integral to be real, there is not a simpler method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\operatorname{Re}(\rho)>0$ and $q \in \mathbb C$ is fixed. Your integral is
$$
K_q (\rho ) = \mathrm{e}^{ - \rho } \int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - \rho (\cosh (R) - 1)} \cosh (Rq)\mathrm{d}R} .
$$
Now perform the change of variables $t = \frac{1}{2}(\cosh (R) - 1)$, to deduce
$$
K_q (\rho ) = \mathrm{e}^{ - \rho } \int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - 2\rho t} t^{ - 1/2} \frac{{\cosh (q\cosh ^{ - 1} (1 + 2t))}}{{\sqrt {1 + t} }}\mathrm{d}t} .
$$
Using [$(15.4.13)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E13), we find
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\cosh (q\cosh ^{ - 1} (1 + 2t))}}{{\sqrt {1 + t} }} &= \frac{{(\sqrt {1 + t}  + \sqrt t )^{2q}  + (\sqrt {1 + t}  - \sqrt t )^{2q} }}{{2\sqrt {1 + t} }} \\ &= {}_2F_1 \!\left( {q + \tfrac{1}{2}, - q + \tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}; - t} \right),
\end{align*}
where ${}_2F_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function. Therefore,
$$
K_q (\rho ) = \mathrm{e}^{ - \rho } \int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - 2\rho t} t^{ - 1/2} {}_2F_1\! \left( {q + \tfrac{1}{2}, - q + \tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}; - t} \right)\mathrm{d}t} .
$$
Now you can apply [Watson's lemma](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.4.i) to deduce the [familiar asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.E2) of the modified Bessel function $K_q (\rho )$ in the sector $|\arg \rho|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}-\delta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. By studying the properties of the hypergeometric function, you can actually show that this expansion is valid in the larger sector $|\arg \rho|\leq \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta<\frac{3\pi}{2}$.